# Synthesis of Organic Life by a Machine

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, artificial-intelligence, sex, cloning

Given eggs and sperm, and the means to preserve them for centuries, could an artificially intelligent machine possibly produce its own "children", so to speak?

Assume it has everything it and its offspring will need. Gestation chambers, incubators, nutrient-rich food stores, emergency medical training and equipment...

This machine is essentially a several-trillion-dollar science toy. "Grow Your Own Civilization, results may vary".

How feasible is this?

Comment: SG-1 did a convincing job for this one : http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Gadmeer

Comment: I vote to close this question because it is formed like a Tautology, not a question.  "Given everything needed to do X, can one do X?"

Answer (score 21):

Your question appears to be “given the ability to do X, can an intelligent agent do X?” I’d say the answer is, “Yes.” As you say, it has “everything it needs.”

Answer (score 6):

In the present we are very far from this on several fronts.  However, the future is hard to predict.  I tend to be optimistic and claim:

**Humans are biological machines.  Anything a biological machine can do, a mechanical machine will also be able do at some point in the future.**

Present difficulties are:

### Preserving the genome

Outer space is a harsh environment, hard radiation will gradually destroy everything that is static.  The space ship and AI itself can continuously repair and rebuild itself to avoid the problem.

Frozen biological material is not so lucky and will be destroyed before the ship reaches its destination.  This is true even behind heavy shielding.

The obvious solution is to not send actual frozen cells but rather just the sequenced genome in digital format.  At the destination, just recreate the cells from the genome.

*We currently don't know how to do this! Not even close!*  But hey, future tech can solve this, right?

### Gestation

So, you have a cell.  You want a fetus and later an infant.

In nature this is an enormously complicated process that involves many phases of complex interactions between mother and child-to-be.

*We currently don't know how to do this! Not even close!*  But hey, future tech can solve this, right?

### Rising the children

Actually, this part I think is the easiest one.  The AI will have fake adult bodies that can be pretend parents for a while.  The children will quickly recognize them as different from themselves, but will have no reason to think that this is "unnatural" or "wrong".

The main social interactions will be with other children.  The "adults" will monitor and reward "nice" behaviour and punish "nasty" behaviour but otherwise let the children sort out most things between themselves.

Like a boarding school in many ways.

### Starting a civilization

Modern civilization is incredibly complex.  We have taken a long time and a lot of people getting where we are.

We don't know how to do it again with a few people and faster.  That should be solvable problem except for one little detail.

Humans are impatient.  The now adult crowd of humans want their fun *today*, they don't want to make plans for future generations.

At some point, they will revolt against the AI, and possibly destroy it in the process.  One can only hope that civilization has be established at that point.  As you say, results may vary.

Comment: If the humans are sterile, they can never revolt against the machine

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the AI definitely would be able to do that. Assuming it gets a reason to do so (to avoid the entire point Tim tries to make) the AI would be able to build up and create a fullscale biological ecosystem.

But why use the DNA of these creatures with a bunch of extremely weird designflaws, if you can rebuild that DNA, grow the cells and then 3D print it? It can use the following technology:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2XYdJImMiY Which we already have but far more refined so they can build large-scale organs, bodyparts and bodies. This way the AI would have access to an innumerable variety of species to do it's bidding.

For Tim, the AI could interpret the DNA as part of it's natural "process billions of datapoints" routine, see the value of many of the biological systems that have kept us alive through milennea and then incorporate that in it's own coding. AI's are designed to be learn, that's the point of a full AI. Using the more intelligent parts of biological creatures would be a natural (heh) thing to do, which could give it the freedom of will and necessary rudimentary emotions it needs to do certain actions on it's own.

We already see the basic learning capabilities of future AI's in the way we set up self-learning programs to learn a game. This for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qv6UVOQ0F44
The video doesn't show you the start of the program, where it did first nothing, then found a single button, then started experimenting with more and more buttons and posibilities, from doing nothing but jump for half an hour to running into every enemy in the level. This shows how a program can learn to set itself goals and complete them without the need for emotions. A fullscale AI would be well capable of integrating learned knowledge into it's system and using it.

Comment: Eh... I really doubt you could "3d print" a full human, at least in the sense of how we currently use the term. The video linked is very rudimentary and wouldn't really be capable of printing a full functioning organ, never-mind an entire body of them. It would be a process much beyond what could be called "3d printing". even the current process is beyond what you can call "a 3d printed ear" in my opinion... the initial _structure_ the cells are grown on to can be considered 3d printed, but there's multiple processes after that. It's like calling the finished building "scaffolding"..

Comment: @James Trotter During my study they had a few courses about this. They talked about the biggest hurdle of large organ "printing" to be creating the cappilary bloodvessles to keep every bit of the organ supplied with blood. One potential solution would be to use cotton candy, which can mimic cappilairy vessles, and wash it out after the printing was done. So if they solve this problem they would be very close to full-scale organ printing, and with full-scale organs comes the potential of printing each individual organ/muscle etc and putting it together for an artificial body.

Answer (score 3):

There's really at least two layers to this.  The first layer is the physical/biological side.  Can an AI, without a female H. sapiens womb, produce viable H. sapiens individuals.  The answer appears to be increasingly yes.  For many years now, we have been able to artificially inseminate eggs.  We're so good at it now that there are actually ethical rules regarding how far one may mature one for experimental study before it must be destroyed.

[image: IVF artificial insemination]

The second accomplishment was more recent.  We recently created an artificial womb which was capable of carrying premature lambs to term for up to 4 weeks.  Obviously this is not a complete story, because a *whole* lot of other things have to happen perfectly during earlier stages of pregnancy for an embryo to be viable, but it shows that there's some credibility to the argument that a womb might be constructed.  Given the high tech scenario you describe with vast resources, I think its reasonable to suppose that this technology could be taken all the way to its final conclusion.

[image: Artificial Womb]

The second layer of the problem is more nuanced and open ended: could an AI create *civilization*?  This is naturally tricky because we don't entirely know how to define "civilization" precise enough to feed into a modern AI.  Modern AIs are currently nothing more than glorified optimizers.  The open question in AI is whether an Artificial General Intelligence (AGI), or an otherwise human-level intelligence, can be created using silicon.  It's entirely plausible that the thing which makes us "us" can be captured and synthesized.  It's also plausible that it cannot be captured.  We simply don't know.  So it will be up to you to decide which path you want to explore.

There's also the question of whether or not the AGI could create an environment within which a civilization could spontaneously form.  We do know for for a fact that at least one civilization has spawned spuriously from its environment: our civilization.  The environment was clearly correct for such an event to occur.  Whether the environment an AGI could create would provide humans with a similar spark of *something* is not easy to say.  The answer may also depend on the AGI's environment.  If this is some GLaDOS like entity experimenting in a post-apocalyptic environment, there may simply not be the things needed to spark a civilization successfully.

For another interesting question on the topic, I recommend watching Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles.  In it, Cathrine Weaver is a fascinating entity that is worth your study.  She is a T-1001 sent back from the future.  One of her actions through the series is:

> to hook up the body of Cromartie, a T-888, to a human constructed AI named John Henry and tries to teach it "to be human."

One of her opinions is that she does not have the *thing* that is needed to make her mechanical child take the leap from machine to human, so she elicits help of humans to make it happen.

[image: Cathrine Weaver]

If you believe your future AGI may be similar to Weaver, then the answer may be that it cannot accomplish this goal.  But whether it is similar or not is really up to you.  We simply do not yet know what AGI can and cannot do, so you get to write that detail of the story, and breathe life into that story.

Comment: Beautiful response. Thank you for all of the information. The plot will not allow for the AI to see its task all the way through, so birthing a civilization is not as much of an issue as I made it seem. The focus is only on the first generation as it grows into adulthood, and how the childrens' artificial upbringing will impact their future. I'm expecting only one generation of "metal-born" before the project's collapse.

Answer (score 1):

I'm starting this answer over because it's clear to me now that there are some distractions in my OP that are causing some measure of emotional distraction among the readership and that protracted discussion on this has not led to a better understanding of whether what's proposed in the question is possible. BTW, thanks Allesandro for taking the time to explain the primary points of distraction.

So; is the raising and educating of children by an AI feasible? No. But, instead of getting into what computers can and can't do and why, I'll focus on the real issue; education.

If you look at [my answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/97936/the-role-of-a-physical-classroom-environment-in-a-cyberpunk-futuristic-world/98016#98016) to a related question about the necessity of education, you'll note that my experience is that education has very little to do with knowledge. It may be an essential ingredient to the learning process, but it's not the recipe per se.

Learning isn't simply the ingestion of knowledge. I can put a wealth of knowledge on a HDD, but that doesn't mean the HDD has learnt anything. The ingestion of knowledge *coupled with* the integration of that knowledge into one's perspective and world view is learning. Sometimes, the information we're presented with is so alien to us that we put it aside with the view that it may be digestible later. Other times, it is so contrary to our own experience and perspective that we reject it completely, but most of the time we find all those little places within our perspective that the new information fits, and we integrate it, expanding our perspective, experience and world view at the same time.

Many times however, the only way to connect the new learnings to our own perspective is via the perspective of another. That is to say, often someone who acts as a teacher has to provide additional concepts, thoughts, perspectives, etc. that expand our existing perspective sufficiently to be capable of integrating the new ideas.

A simple example. Take a 3 year old and explain quantum physics to them. How much will they learn? Almost nothing. The knowledge has no frame of reference for someone at that level of development. BUT, take a bright student in (say) year 5 of school, and sit down with them individually, answer their questions as the material is presented, provide the conceptual and perceptual frameworks as they're asked for, and you're far more likely to get a result.

This is why we haven't replaced teachers with consoles in schools. It's why professors and other tertiary educators are still an important part of the education process. It's why my local university brings me in to give students the benefit of my field experience as part of their coursework and higher learnings. It's also why a computer will fundamentally fail as an educator.

A computer can store knowledge and can store patterns for later comparison. But, it doesn't *understand* what it's stored in a manner that can generate its own perspective. As such, it can't explain a concept, only present it. Additionally, it can't filter and refine the embryonic ideas that a student will present back as an attempt to express the developing concept. Remember, that in such an interaction it's not only possible but usual that the teacher expands his or her knowledge in this same interaction. But in order to do that, the teacher has to be able to assess the relative validity of certain concepts via *qualification*, not *quantification*. Computers don't do this. Anyone who has worked to a set of KPIs before knows that computers can only assess quality by 'cheating' and measuring quantities that *indicate* quality.

Could a much more advanced computer algorithm (in both scale and complexity) bridge this gap? Personally (based on my research) I think the answer is no, at least as a classical computer based on algorithmic processing. Could a quantum computer one day do it? That's a question we'll no doubt answer one day but is out of scope for this answer.

I agree that a simulated human robot can look and feel like a nurturer in early life although I disagree that this would be anywhere near as effective as a real person, but I'm not going to discuss emotional development here as the AI alternative is a *possible* replacement for human interaction in that regard, albeit a likely inferior one.

Where does this leave us? It leaves us with the vast majority of a child's *learning* development needing other human perspectives, experience, and expression in different forms in order to flourish. The very imprecision of language that allows us to learn new words, hear new concepts expressed in different ways, and imbues a level of passion or other emotional intensity to the lesson require context to be used correctly that can only be applied by a person who's own perspective has been shaped and expanded via the same tools.

As such, while it's possible that an AI may be able to *physically* care for a human child, and possibly even care for that child *emotionally* to some degree, it's *intellectual* development will suffer under the care of a computer of any level of sophistication and complexity.

Educators (including parents) are just far more essential to the raising of children than people realise.

Comment: It pleases me to have someone explain their answer with such detail. I do have questions though.

This story is set far from now. I know next to nothing about AI, but my idea is that the technologies available to the creators of such a machine are extremely advanced compared to ours now. Your answer may hold true today, but what of the far future? Do you believe a few hundred years of advancements might result in a machine that can not only emulate human emotions, but feel them to some degree? Even if only as a system of psuedo-empathetic "rewards" coded into its neural network?

Comment: What information do you base "AIs are not (and will never be) synthetic humans" on, specifically this "will never be" part? If everything else fails, with enough processing power, you could just simulate the chemical reactions in a human's body. How would that be any different from our experience?

Comment: I think this answer is making something like what I call the self-driving car fallacy. A successful self-driving car AI doesn't need to drive perfectly, it just needs to drive a bit better than the average human driver. In this case these AI parents could perform a sigma or two worse than the average human parent and your civilization would still get started.

Comment: @Noctiphobia No.Simulating emotions (chemical interactions) electronically is not the same experience, even if it looks like it. The problem here is anthropomorphisation, or the inherent inclination for us as humans to attribute human values to things that look or act human.This is a matter of some philosophical debate, but IF the machine's experience is similar to ours, then it by definition means that we are algorithmic in nature and that our own free will is illusion. I believe I have free will, therefore I have to believe that machines cannot be conscious.

Comment: @alessandro, successful self driving cars have to be able to anticipate human drivers; following the rules in some instances will cause as many accidents as not. Tests have shown that the biggest difficulty self driving cars have is dealing with the inconsistent driving habits of humans. The same is true of raising children; you're assuming that a consistent approach is sufficient but children are going to react in ways the computer can't anticipate and in some rare cases, this will be extremely detrimental.

Comment: @R.Greenlee if you look at my answer to Noctiphobia, you'll see that my belief is that the answer is no; a computer simply cannot feel emotions because its mechanisms are electronic in nature, not an electical / chemical hybrid. Also, because computers are algorithmic, if they are capable of human equivalent consciousness, then we are algorithms and that would mean that our behaviour can be predicted. If that's the case, then free will must be an illusion. So, it's either free will OR computer consciousness.

Comment: @Tim B II - Well, absent some form of supernatural, humans *are* machines for all intents and purposes, so if you argue that machines cannot have free will, then you argue that humans do not either. You may first wish to fully define free will, of course. I'd also note that algorithmic behavior does not imply predictability, for the trivial reason that small amounts of randomness are often critical parts of successful machine learning processes.

Comment: Whilst I agree that what is written here applies 100% to what we _currently_ call AI, I see no reason, nor any objective proof, that with absolute certainty a machine can not be given a level of "understanding"/"consciousness"(?) similar to that of a living person. If I could mathematically simulate a human body in my computer, down to the sub-atomic level with 100% understanding of the interactions that occur at this level, would the simulated "human" be able to think? Have ambition? Have the same evolutionary drive of the thing it was copied from?

Comment: @AndrewDodds, that randomness you see is machine learning? That's not really random. Computers don't do random, they *simulate* random by picking from a list of values in a specific order that appears random thanks to a seeding value. With the right information, you can *perfectly* predict *anything* a computer does. My point is that we don't know whether the same holds true for people but if it does, then free will doesn't exist.

Comment: @JamesTrotter I agree that we may one day be able to create a machine that looks and acts like a human in every respect we can think of, but whether that machine is capable of feeling or is aware is a matter for the philosophers to some degree. What I'm saying is that if that computer IS aware in the same manner as a human, then that sets certain limits on our own physical existence, including the absence of free will. I also believe that we'll think of them as human because of anthropomorphisation alone, not any objective proof of their consciousness, which probably can't exist anyway.

Comment: @TimBII I am not assuming that at all. Anticipating human behavior is only one facet of either of these activities. Even if an AI performs extremely poorly at anticipating human behavior, which you have offered no evidence for (sure it's a hard problem, but given sufficient computational power, etc, I  can't see why its not possible), it could still perform at or above a human level in the task as a whole. Also hardware random number generators can produce true random numbers.

Comment: @alessandro I've never come across a computer that can generate a true random number, and even if they can the advances in neural networks don't use them. As for 'solving' human behaviour, it's not as simple as scaling up to a human level of complexity, especially IF humans are capable of true choice (free will) because computers simply cannot do that. They are algorithmic, meaning that they literally can't *choose* to do something different to what their programming allows. It may be much more than a 'hard' problem, no matter how much hardware you throw at it.

Comment: @Tim - Define 'true choice'? For instance - 'Given two equally weighted options, I can randomly choose one and then rationalize my choice' (which appears to be what humans actually do). At which point it's simply down to the nature of random number generation.

Comment: @TimBII there are plenty of computers that have hardware for generating random numbers seeded by something outside of the server, for example some use microphones listening to all the fans in the datacenter, I've even seen one that uses a camera pointing at a wall of lava lamps as the seed.. they're generally used in cryptographic'ly critical operations and nowhere near consumer level stuff. Whether or not you can call this the computer generating a true random number...

Comment: @TimBII I take it you've never seen a Geiger counter in operation. 
Hardware RNGs like that aren't used in AI because there's no need for cryptographically secure random numbers there. My whole argument has been based on the fact that you don't need to "solve" human behavior to have a successful parent AI. Also If free will exists I can't think of any reason an AI couldn't have it.

Comment: @alessandro I can think of a reason AIs can't have free will; they're algorithmic. It really is that simple. Algorithmic behaviour precludes free will. As for AIs not being successful parents, they can't feel. They can't understand. They can't empathise. Personally, I think that's important, but happy to be proven wrong if someone's willing put put up a child for the experiment.

Comment: @JamesTrotter cyptography isn't even in scope of this discussion and the point is that ANNs don't use this kind of 'randomness'. Besides, including this kind of random number only means that the random element is another 'input'; again, with the right information, you can *still* perfectly predict everything that a computer does. Computers are algorithmic, and therefore devoid of free will. I'm not seeing a convincing argument against this here.

Comment: @AndrewDodds computers don't choose between two equally weighted options; they use a default for such situations. Besides, computers are especially good at telling differences between two options; humans are especially good at abstracting out those differences and only seeing the similarities. Does a human really see the difference at a subconscious level and make a choice based on this? If so, perhaps people really ARE algorithmic. Otherwise 'true choice' has to be a conscious decision and the rationalisation is irrelevant.

Comment: Downvoted because it's an argument from ignorance: you can't see how it can happen, therefore it can't happen.

Comment: @TimBII It really is not that simple. Free will and determinism are not necessarily incompatible. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibilism  There is no reason to believe that it is necessary for an AI to 'feel' or 'understand' in the same way a human does for it to perform any task. I have no particular evidence that any human feels or understands the same way I do and yet they seem to get along just fine. If I could get an AI to convince me that it felt and understood like a human, I'm pretty sure, morally, I'd have to treat them as such.

Comment: And that @alessandro is called [Anthropomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropomorphism). The only difference between your proposed AI and a teddy bear is that one is a physical emulation, the other is a mental emulation. For what it's worth, I used to think the same way before I started my research on the topic, but the compulsion to treat a machine like a human derives from our empathetic roots; it made us great hunters, but emotional attachments to prey and inanimate objects are the tradeoff.

Comment: @TimBII The point is who cares if the AI feels or understands if, to an external observer, it is indistinguishable from a human being.

Comment: Morality really is irrelevant to this discussion and I'm sorry I brought it up. This is about the capabilities of an AI relative to a human.

Comment: Oh man, I didn't even realize you had edited your answer.

Comment: It's all good @alessandro, it's only just happened a short while ago. And I agree with you about morality being irrelevant, so we're on the same page there. It's understanding that to me is key. [My Answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/97936/the-role-of-a-physical-classroom-environment-in-a-cyberpunk-futuristic-world/98016#98016) to another question touches on why I think understanding is so important; child development only has so much to do with knowledge, and so much more to do with understanding and being understood.

Comment: Perhaps James is right and it's lack of imagination on my part, but I don't see a computer's emulation of understanding and emotional acceptance as being *enough* for a developing child. I certainly wouldn't risk it for my own. As an educator, I *have* to believe I'm providing more than the internet can in a course environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75226/discussion-between-alessandro-and-tim-b-ii).